# What do you call the decoration on a dress?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Is there a term that refers to the decoration on a piece of cloth? I am wondering if there's a particular word for it.

Answer (score 1):

The decoration in this photograph is lace.

Comment: This particular dress is decorated with lace, as Paul says. You could say the lace has been _applied_ to it. Other dresses may be decorated with embroidery, or made from a fabric that has a pattern woven into or printed on it.